# DAX - Apply filters and check if the record is a particular category then output 1, else 0

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

I have a requirement like this,

```
    P.No.   BR  IND   SC    TD         RM          CD         PD      Out - Col - Required
    1        B  N     T    2/1/2011 2/1/2011    5/1/2007    1/1/2007    1
    1        B  N     T    2/1/2011 2/1/2011    5/1/2010    2/1/2011    1
    1        B  N     T    2/1/2011 6/1/2019    5/1/2007    2/1/2011    0
    1        B  N     T    2/1/2011 1/1/2019    5/1/2007    2/1/2011    0
```

THE `Out-Col-Required` is what I am trying to do using `DAX - Calculated Column`.

This is the Logic that it follows,

Filter the Table for the following first in `DAX`,

1. `BR = B, IND = N, SC = T, TD = RM`
2. Then identify the Min CD date and Max PD date for P.No.

if the diff is less than *30 months*, then `1 else 0`.

Kindly help me with this.

Thanks.

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: @PratikBhavsar sorry couldn't proceed because of the min date calculation with filter context.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Out =
VAR PNo = OutCol[P.No.]
VAR filt =
    FILTER (
        OutCol;
        OutCol[P.No.] = PNo
            && OutCol[TD] = OutCol[RM]
            && OutCol[BR] = "B"
            && OutCol[IND] = "N"
            && OutCol[SC] = "T"
    )
VAR monthsDiff =
    CALCULATE (
        DATEDIFF (
            MIN ( OutCol[CD] );
            MAX ( OutCol[PD] );
            MONTH
        );
        filt
    )
RETURN
    IF (
        OutCol[TD] = OutCol[RM]
            && OutCol[BR] = "B"
            && OutCol[IND] = "N"
            && OutCol[SC] = "T"
            && monthsDiff < 30;
        1;
        0
    )
```